# Strange entry in WP8 AppManifest.xml

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

When I tried to upload my xaml to the marketplace, I got the error `1016: A file registered in the app manifest is missing: Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.dll. Use a different one and then try again`. I looked into the generated `WMAppManifest.xml` and, of course, it was there.

The problem is that I don't use any map-related functionality in my app, and I cannot say where this came from. I didn't have this problem the last time I uploaded this app.

The biggest changes since last time are new ads (AdDuplex and AdMob). Is it possible that this entry was caused by one of them? How can I prevent this entry to be created?

PS: I'm parallely developing the same app on WP7 (different git branches), and I didn't have the problem there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is being pulled in by the ad frameworks (I believe AdMob is the culprit) - add the file to your solution and you should be fine shipping it.

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't it have been included automatically if it also worked when running it on a device? Anyway, it worked after a couple of steps: I cleaned the project and re-built, also had to remove doubled Microsoft Ad libraries. It works now. Though now completely sure what did the trick.